# Trying to render data from database in a html table using Django framework

Tags: python, django

I have created a GPU database which I want to render in HTML format using Django MVT.

This is "urls.py" script inside the 'graphicsCard' [*'graphicsCard' is the app name*]

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('products', views.productViews, name='products')
]
```

views.py of *graphicsCard*

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Products
# Create your views here.
def productViews(request):
    allproduct = Products.objects.all()
    context = {
        'allproduct': allproduct
    }
    return render(request, 'Products.html', context)
```

html template called as "products.html"

```
{% extends 'homepage.html' %}
<!-- {% load %} -->
{% block content %}
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-2 bg-info">
        Menu
    </div>    
        <table class="col-10 table table-dark py-0 my-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">First</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last</th>
                    <th scope="col">Handle</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               {% for x in allproduct %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{% x.name %}</td>
                        <td>First</td>
                        <td>Last</td>
                        <td>Handle</td>
                    </tr>
               {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

when I run *python manage.py shell* and type

```
product = Products.objects.all()
product[1].name
```

it sends the data from the database but I cannot figure out this error called *"Error during template rendering"* followed by

*"Invalid block tag on line 21: 'x.name', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"*

Comment: It is not a block {% x.name %} is  {{ x.name }}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need **`{{ }}`** to render the variables in template

```
   {% for x in allproduct %}      
       {{ x.name }}
     {% endfor %}
```